# How to add line breaks (and other whitespace) to the page source from an ASPX file

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

When I create an ASP.NET page with Visual Studio, some of the line breaks in the ASPX file are ignored when the page source is viewed. For example, the following ASPX code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page Title</title>

    <meta id="MetaTag1" content="First item of information">
    <meta id="MetaTag2" content="Second item of information">
    <meta id="MetaTag3" content="Third item of information, containing longer description">
    <meta id="MetaTag4">
    <meta id="MetaTag5" content="Fifth item of information">
    <meta id="MetaTag6">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function button_pressed() {
            document.getElementById('SubmitButton').style.borderWidth = '8px 5px 4px 7px';
            [etc...]
```

shows up like this when I view the page source:

```
<head><title>
    My Page Title
</title><meta id="MetaTag1" content="First item of information"><meta id="MetaTag2" content
="Second item of information"><meta id="MetaTag3" content="Third item of information, conta
ining longer description"><meta id="MetaTag4"><meta id="MetaTag5" content="Fifth item of in
formation"><meta id="MetaTag6">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function button_pressed() {
            document.getElementById('SubmitButton').style.borderWidth = '8px 5px 4px 7px';
            [etc...]
```

Most of the line breaks and whitespace in the ASPX file are also in the page source, but in some cases the line breaks are ignored (even the double line break between `</title>` and the first `<meta>` tag). In other cases  whitespace that wasn't present in the ASPX file is seen in the page source (or at least one case - the `<title>` tag).

This seems to be an issue with how ASP.NET interprets the ASPX file, as opposed to the browser or Visual Studio, because the page source looks the same in FireFox, IE, and Chrome, and editing the ASPX file in a text editor instead of VS doesn't make a difference.

I'm wondering why some of the whitespace in the ASPX file is ignored when the large majority of it does make it to the HTML source (I only showed a representative sample focusing on the problematic part, but most of the rest of the page source has formatting that largely corresponds to the ASPX).

But more importantly, I'd like to know how to add line breaks in the ASPX file that will make the page source more readable but will *not* be rendered on the web page.

---

**Some solutions that are less than ideal:**

- Obviously, a `<br />` at the end of each line isn't what I want. While that does add a line break in the page source, it gets rendered on the page, adding useless whitespace at the top.
- I can add `&#10;` at the end of each line. That's better, because it doesn't add whitespace to the rendered page, but it shows up explicitly in the page source, making it look cluttered.
- I can put all the information in one `<meta>` tag, and add `&#10`s between the various items in the **content** attibute. If I do that, the information lines up vertically, and the `&#10`s aren't shown. While that's the part that most needs to be readable, this only works for the contents of an attribute value. Also, for some of the `<meta>`s, the content is set explicitly in the ASPX, and for others it's set by the code-behind, so doing it this way complicates things.
- I'm aware that there are some browser-dependent solutions, but I don't want to rely on those. I'd like the line breaks to actually be in the page source.

Comment: Well, I came with another idea. If I add `<%:"\n"%>` to the end of the line, that adds a line break in the page source without showing any additional clutter (as in the case of `&#10;`). But using code blocks just to add line breaks to the source is rather kludgy. Does anyone know of a pure ASPX solution? And can anyone explain why the line breaks are ignored only in few parts?? It's especially ironic that one of the few places that line breaks are ignored is around <meta> tags in the header, given that the primary purpose of <meta> tags is to be viewed in the page source!

Comment: `"given that the primary purpose of <meta> tags is to be viewed in the page source!"`    I think the primary purposes are to be read by search engines and give hints to the browser on how to render the content.   BTW:  I never noticed this before and now it bugs me!   I like things lined up too.

Answer (score -1):

> "But more importantly, I'd like to know how to add line breaks in the ASPX file that will make the page source more readable but will not be rendered on the web page."

So long as your element's style has a [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property that is not set to preserve whitespace, whitespace such as line breaks in your aspx should not be visible in your browser.

Comment: A css style would not effect how the literal html text is displayed when viewing the source.

Comment: Agreed. However, the portion of the question in quotes would seem to indicate that the poster is concerned with _both_ how the page's source is displayed in a text editor _as well as_ with how said source is displayed by a browser, which would be affected by the element's css style.

Comment: No, that's a misunderstanding of what I'm saying. "Page source" is referring to the browser feature for viewing the source of a web page. By "how to add line breaks in the ASPX file that will make the page source more readable", I don't mean how to add line breaks that will make the ASPX file more readable when viewed in an editor. The way to do that is to hit the [Enter] key. I'm asking what can be added in the ASPX file that will create a line break in the page source viewed from a browser, without adding a line break to the rendered web page and without adding clutter to the page source.